# How to change DRY a spec to avoid deprecation warning "The implicit block expectation syntax is deprecated, you should pass a block..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have to following rspec fragment:

```
describe "Create with a classification class added" do
  before do
    @lambda_block = lambda {
      click_button I18n.t(:button_save)
      expect(page).to have_text(I18n.t :'flash.classification_scheme.create_success')
    }     
  end   

  describe "Save should create a ClassificationScheme and a ClassificationSchemesClass" do
    subject { @lambda_block }
    it { is_expected.to change(ClassificationScheme, :count).by(1) }
    it { is_expected.to change(ClassificationSchemesClass, :count).by(1) }
  end   
end
```

I get these deprecation warnings:

*The implicit block expectation syntax is deprecated, you should pass a block rather than an argument to `expect` to use the provided block expectation matcher or the matcher must implement `supports_value_expectations?`. e.g  `expect { value }.to change` ClassificationScheme.count `by 1` not `expect(value).to change` ClassificationScheme.count `by 1`*

*The implicit block expectation syntax is deprecated, you should pass a block rather than an argument to `expect` to use the provided block expectation matcher or the matcher must implement `supports_value_expectations?`. e.g  `expect { value }.to change` ClassificationSchemesClass.count `by 1` not `expect(value).to change` ClassificationSchemesClass.count `by 1`*

The deprecation warnings disappear if I change the spec as follows. **expect** gets a block instead of an argument, however two lines are repeated, the code is not DRY.

```
describe "Create with a classification class added" do 
  it "Save should create a ClassificationScheme" do
    expect{
      click_button I18n.t(:button_save)
      expect(page).to have_text(I18n.t :'flash.classification_scheme.create_success')
    }.to change{ClassificationScheme.count}.by(1)
  end

  it "Save should create a ClassificationSchemesClass" do
    expect{
      click_button I18n.t(:button_save)
      expect(page).to have_text(I18n.t :'flash.classification_scheme.create_success')
    }.to change{ClassificationSchemesClass.count}.by(1)
  end
end
```

How can I pass the lambda block to expect?

If I try `expect{@lambda_block}.to change...` then the lambda block is not executed. If I try `expect(@lambda_block).to change...` then the test is passed, however I get again the deprecation warning.

The question is, how can I pass the *@lambda_block* to *expect* but avoid the deprecation warning.

I'm currently to migrate a project from rails 5 to rails 6, so the current versions:
rails 6.0.6.1
rspec 3.12.0
rspec-rails 5.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make it nice and clear to see what you have, I've simplified this a bit:

```rb
subject do
  lambda { click_button I18n.t(:button_save) }     
end
it { is_expected.to change(ClassificationScheme, :count).by(1) }
```

---

When you change to explicit block, you no longer need *lambda*:

```rb
subject do
  click_button I18n.t(:button_save)    
end
it { expect { subject }.to change(ClassificationScheme, :count).by(1) }
#           ^         ^
# the block is already being passed to expect, this is where your lambda used to be
```

When you put *lambda* inside of that block, the blocks become nested and *lambda* never gets called. Which you can also fix by calling it yourself:

```rb
subject do
  lambda { click_button I18n.t(:button_save) }     
end
it { expect { subject.call }.to change(ClassificationScheme, :count).by(1) }
```

When you don't use a block syntax `{ }` or `do end`, `subject` becomes an argument, which is deprecated:

```rb
#               block has to go here vvvvvv
def expect(arg = nil, keyword: :arg, &block)
# not here ^^^  
end
```

You can use ruby unary `&` operator to treat passed argument as a block:

```rb
subject do
  lambda { click_button I18n.t(:button_save) }     
end
it { expect(&subject).to change(ClassificationScheme, :count).by(1) }
```

This one is hard to explain quick:
*https://medium.com/@amliving/rubys-unary-operator-a93d36d3cd8b*